# counting words on in an string consisting alphabets,\n,\t and space characters

Tags: c++, string

Given a string consisting of spaces,\t,\n and alphabets,task is to count the number of words where spaces,\t and \n work as separators.
For this problem, I wrote following code, which doesn't works properly, and suggestions why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
bool isalpha(char ch)
{
    if((ch>='A'&& ch<='Z')||(ch>='a'&& ch<='z'))
       return true;
    return false;
}
int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string str;
        int count=0;
        getline(cin,str);
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(isalpha(str[i]))
            {
                count++;
                while(str[i]!='\n'||str[i]!='\t'||str[i]!=' ')
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
               continue;
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you reimplement [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: As for your problem I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: 1. Does `29/6/2017` count as a word? 2. Where do you store the count of words? In `i`?

Comment: it has only alphabets,\n,\t and spaces as input, and count is stored in variable    count

Comment: So, 1. If the input is made of letters, only, why do you call isalpha? 2. Why do you increment i?

Comment: The first `cin` will leave a newline (if you *enter* a number) in the stream which will be read by the first `getline`.

Comment: @Bob__so i should use cin.ignore() right?